# How to retrieve exact user-agent string from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, user-agent, google-analytics-api

We have an interesting 'bug' in our JS code that only fires when a user agent has a specific combination of parameters -- specifically when IE8 sends both Trident/4.0 and MSIE 6.0;

We have checked the GA export data; it appears to export only the pre-digested browser information:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html#browser.

Forum post 87919 on forums.digitalpoint.com (link removed since I'm a n00b)
refers to pulling a cross-segment report for more detail; however, that no longer appears to be on the GA front end interface.

Why do we need this instead of just fixing it?  If it turns out it only impacts a few users, we can schedule the fix later in the cycle; if it's impacting 20% of our base, it becomes far sooner to fix.

So, the question - how can we pull a specific User Agent string from GA; pull all UA strings from GA or run a Regex against GA to get a count of a matching UA string?

We're also working with the SA team to enable UA logging on the apache level (very high volume website; logging is turned way down).

Comment: You can't retrieve the exact user agent string from GA. The only way to do that is either to log it yourself, or to look through your own server logs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best you're going to get out of the Data Export API (or the Google Analytics interface) is processed information: browser / browser version (Internet Explorer / 8.0). There is no way to get the original user-agent string.

Also note that if you have a high volume website you're going to run into data sampling especially if you're looking at a date range beyond larger than a day or two ([more on sampling](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsSampling.html#reportSampling)).